# Semisimple Lie groups with infinite center

Tags: reference-request, lie-groups

Is there a classification of all connected semisimple Lie groups with infinite center?

I know there is the universal cover of $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ and I know it is the only contractible semisimple Lie group (up to direct products etc.), so in particular its maximal compact subgroup is trivial.

Is there a connected semisimple Lie groups with infinite center and non-trivial compact subgroups? (other than things like $\widetilde{SL}(2,\mathbb{R}) \times SO(3, \mathbb{R})$, etc.)

Comment: Are you familiar with the symplectic group?

Comment: You mean $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$, right? From a quick look, it seems that it is a real, non-compact, connected, simple Lie group with fundamental group isomorphic to the integers. So I guess its universal cover will have center isomorphic to the integers, right? If I understand correctly, its universal cover is not contractible because the maximal compact subgroup of $Sp(2n, \mathbb{R})$, unlike $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ has a non-trivial semisimple part. Thanks.

Comment: Right although the last sentence is wrong. The true reason is that the maximal compact is not the circle group but $U(n)$.